# Validate textbox when another textbox contains text

Tags: c#, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

I've been trying to get validation working on my textboxes and the only thing that works is setting

```
  autoPostBack=true
```

and in a postback textbox_change event add

```
 textBox3.Validator.Enabled = true;
```

But i've noticed that chrome and edge dosent always fire the postback event and validation is then never activated. And it is'nt user friendly to do a postback for such a small thing as just add validation. It must be a easier way..

So i've got this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"/>   <--- Dont need validation on that one, when starting to type values are populated from a ajax call
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"/>   <--- Here i want to add validation when txt1 contains something, no validation should fire if the user steps in on txt1 and then out without writing text
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txt2Validator" runat="server" Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="" Display="Static" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="valgroup1" ControlToValidate="txt2"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" />   <--- also validate this only when txt1 contains text
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ddl1Validator" runat="server" Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="" Display="Static" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="valgroup1" ControlToValidate="ddl1"/>
```

So is there a way in jquery to set the required field validators to Enabled=true when txt1 contains text maybe with an onblur event?

Partly solved

Ok so i was a little to fast to not think for my self... 
I've struggled all day to find errors in my ajax request and when that got fixed i was so out of thinking juice and just gave up and asked this questiong. But with the knowing that this shouldent be an issue i tried som coding and ended up with this. It works! YES!
The only thing that i would wont is if i can make it only add validation when txt1 contains text, now validation is enabled as son as i klick in txt1 and then out again. Are there any if this.txt1.contains.text then thing with jQuery?

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=txt2Validator.ClientID%>'), true);
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=ddl1Validator.ClientID%>'), true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.... again to fast to ask a new question..

Solution to my problem:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
            if ($("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").val().length > 0) {
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=txt2Validator.ClientID%>'), true);
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=ddl1Validator.ClientID%>'), true);
            }   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Maybe not the best aproatch but it works.

So the question that stands.. Why ask a question when you know the answer to it? 
Maybe it can help others. (oops did it again, answered my own question )